# Rails 3 sessions not lazy loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've read that sessions in Rails 3 are lazy loaded, but I'm not seeing that behavior. To test this, I created a new Rails 3.2 app using MySQL and the activerecord session store. No gems added except the V8 JavaScript engine. Then I created an empty controller called welcome with an index action. No code in here at all. When I hit the index page, I see a session created in the sessions table in MySQL.

Am I doing something wrong? I thought a session would only be created if I accessed it.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I started looking at this because my sessions table is getting enormous on a production app from all the web crawlers hitting it. Was hoping for an easy way to turn off sessions for them (I've tried kares session_off but ran into some issues). Going to look into using the cookiestore instead of the activerecord store so I don't have to clean up useless sessions in my db all the time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a default behavior of Ruby on Rails beginning from version 3.0 I guess. See:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf

Answer (score 0):

If you need to stop sessions being created in the database for bots/crawlers, this is what worked for me:

```
# Save this file as config/initializers/session_store_ext.rb 
# and don't forget to define BOT_REGEX to match bots/crawlers

class ActiveRecord::SessionStore
  _set_session = instance_method :set_session

  define_method :set_session  do | env, sid, session_data, options |
    unless env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ BOT_REGEX
      _set_session.bind(self).call env, sid, session_data, options
    end

    sid
  end

  private :set_session
end
```

I've written a blog post explaining how I created this and why it works - [Conditionally Disabling Database Sessions in Ruby on Rails 3](http://bugmuncher.com/2015/07/13/conditionally-disabling-database-sessions-rails-3.html)